# Travelling to US through Canada

Tags: transit, canada, b1-b2-visas, pakistani-citizens

I am from Pakistan and hold a Pakistani passport. I have a B1/B2 visa and want to travel to the USA.

Because I want to see a friend of mine in a Canadian airport for a short period of time (e.g. 1 hour), I want to transit through Canada and then travel to the US. So my route would be Islamabad - Dubai - Canada - USA.

For this, do I need a visa for Canada?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I want to visit US and have b1/b2 visa. Can I transit Canada? In other words, Islamabad - Dubai - Canada- US. Is it possible and what are the requirements?

Comment: Okay, then you can click on 'edit' and add this information to the question itself, that will make it much clearer.

Comment: Do note that Toronto Pearson Airport (which is the only Canadian airport with service from Dubai, so I assume it's the one in question here) is not terribly easily accessible from the city center;  it's 31 km away, and the only public transportation to the airport is by bus.  It can easily take 40–60 minutes each way.  Unless you have a really long layover, you should probably stick with your plan of staying at the airport and having your friend visit you there.

Comment: ...  and then I find out that a rail connection from the airport to downtown opened in June 2015 (two months ago.)  I haven't taken it myself, but they claim to be running trains every 15 minutes and that the ride is 25 minutes one way.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, but it is not straight-forward.

Canada's visa requirements for citizens of Pakistan state that you **require a visa to visit or transit** in Canada. If you do still decide to visit your friend, you will have to apply for a tourist visa. If you simply want to transit in Canada ( less than 48h ) then you can apply for a transit visa. Applying for a transit visa is free of cost. <del>However, it is very likely that you will not be able to leave the airport on a transit visa.</del>

The only time a US visa will help you is if you have a green card. A B1/B2 visa does not grant you any exemptions in Canada.

Based on the comments below, it seems like **you are allowed** to exit the airport and the only restriction on your transit visa is the time limit - 48 hours.

Here is a link that should give you more information:
http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp

Comment: Canada is much like the US in that there is no "international" transit area in airports. So everyone must pass through immigration and customs. If you are officially admitted for _any_ purpose, you will be able to leave the airport.

Comment: Plus US has preclearance in Canada anyway.

Comment: "However, it is very likely that you will not be able to leave the airport on a transit visa." I don't think so. Transit means go through Canada; it doesn't mean stay in the airport.

Comment: @user102008: Some countries do have a particular type of transit visa which permits you to land in the country to change planes, but not to leave the airport (you cannot pass immigration).  But I think you're right, Canada doesn't seem to have this.